# Should I Return This Memory Block?

Tags: c++

```
template < typename ArrayType >
ArrayType *VectorToArray( ArrayType **p_ppThisBlock = NULL, vector< ArrayType > *p_vThisVector = NULL )
{
    // Check to see if both parameters are valid.
    if( p_ppThisBlock == NULL || p_vThisVector == NULL )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    else if( p_ppThisBlock != NULL && p_vThisVector != NULL )
    {
        // Create the array that will store the vector's elements dynamically.
        p_ppThisBlock = new ArrayType[ p_vThisVector -> size( ) ];

        // Initialize the array.
        for( unsigned uIndex( 0 ); uIndex < p_vThisVector -> size( ); uIndex++ )
        {
            p_ppThisBlock[ uIndex ] = p_vThisVector[ uIndex ];
        }

        // Return the pointer that pointing to the new block of memory. Is this relevant?   
        return p_ppThisBlock;
    }
}
```

My question is: Is returning the block of memory I created in this function relevant?( Line 12 ).

Comment: Oh my.  Why are you doing this?  Can you not just use `&v[0]`?  At a bare minimum, be sure to use a smart pointer (with an array deleter); otherwise this code is assuredly not exception-safe.

Comment: And in addition to that, what you've written doesn't even work correctly: the assignment `p_ppThisBlock = new ArrayType[...]` is a mismatch between `ArrayType*` and `ArrayType**` (should get a compiler warning here); you want `*p_ppThisBlock = ...`.  Likewise in the for loop, you want `(*p_ppThisBlock)[uIndex] = (*p_vThisVector)[uIndex]`.

Comment: What are you supposed to do when one, but not both, of the pointers is `NULL`?  eg., `VectorToArray(blck, NULL)`?  Right now that case is not handled at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually; failure to do so would cause a memory leak.

If the function is allocating the array and leaving it up to the caller to free the memory, this is fine.  If the caller assumes the memory is freed later (and it isn't from what we see here), memory leak.

Why not return a `vector< vector< ArrayType > >`?

EDIT:

Try giving the method the following signature.

```
template <typename ArrayType>
vector<vector< ArrayType> >& VectorToArray( 
                                 vector< vector< ArrayType > >& _block, 
                                 vector< ArrayType >& _vec )
{
    //No need to check parameters

    //Initialize the array
    for (unsigned uIndex( 0 ); uIndex < _vec.Size(); uIndex++)
    {
         _block.push_back(_vec);
    }

    return _block;
}
```

Same outcome, less error checking, no leaks.  Of course, this requires references instead of raw pointers.

Comment: I could do, but, in my code, I use the "p_ppThisBlock"( Which is external to the function ). Should I return "p_ppThisBlock" at the end?

Comment: You could instead refactor the entire method instead of using raw pointers.  Edited.

Comment: I've never seen a vector of vectors before. Does "vector< vector< int > >" work the same was as "int Array[ 0 ][ 0 ]"?

Comment: `vector<vector<int> >` is subscripted the same way as an `int[][]`; i.e., `v[0][1]`.

Answer (score 1):

There are serious problems with the posted code.  The absolute most obvious problem is that you check to see if two pointers were passed into the function, and if they were you point one of them to something else.  Unless whoever calls your function releases the memory that `p_ppThisBlock` used to point to, you have a definite memory leak.

Additionally, from a philosophical point of view, you are trying to do too much in the function (compare your function to `realloc` -- which may `free` memory, or do nothing, or allocate more memory and change the value of a pointer depending on the arguments passed in).

However, to answer the question that you asked:  yes, it is valid to return a pointer to memory that you allocated via `new`.  That is how allocated memory outlives its scope.  It's part of the reason to have `new`.

```
int* allocateBlockOfIntsUsingAFunction(int numberOfInts)
{
    return new int[numberOfInts];
}
```

As mentioned in another answer, allocating memory and then not telling anybody is a sure road to a memory leak:

```
void leakMemory()
{
    new int[1024];
    return;
}
int main()
{
     while (true)
         leakMemory();
}
```